# How to convert string to json with jsonkit in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, xcode4

How can i do that?
Tried several things like

```
NSString *data2 = [data JSONString];
dataLabel.text = @"%data2%";
```

I want to add some more text to the dataLabel

Answer (score 0):

this will add more text after your json string, i assume that's what you mean?

```
dataLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - more text here", data2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework) to covert it to a JSON object

```
NSString *JSONString = [string JSONRepresentation];
```